# XAML : Set Label Margin inside a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, xamarin, margin, padding

I have a DataTemplate directly inside a Resource Dictionary. Inside the template is a label. The margin property isn't being applied how I expected (it has no effect)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderContainerStyle">
    <Label Margin="10" Text="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

And I can't solve the issue with a border as it appears its illegal (?)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderContainerStyle">
    <Border Padding="10">
        <Label Text="{Binding}"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

I get an error saying cannot resolve symbol Border.

When I try to add it in a ViewCell, application throws an exception:

System.ArgumentException: Value was an invalid value for HeaderTemplate
Parameter name: value

Comment: You've tagged this with both [wpf] and [xamarin], but clearly it cannot be both.  Which is it?  I'd guess Xamarin Forms, since `Border` is obviously a valid type in WPF.

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin.Forms there is no Border class. Instead you should use Frame class which I think is equivalent for Border in WPF.

Like @Nick said, if you want to use DataTemplates in Xamarin.Forms you need to add ViewCell in DataTemplate and then next next element inside that (for example Grid, StackLayout or Label).

If it comes to Padding, in Xamarin.Forms its only applicable for layout (e.g. Grid, StackLayout) classes. Margin can be specified for view (e.g. Label, Button) and layout classes.

Getting back to your code basing on your `HeaderContainerStyle` I think you are trying to create style for Label, right?

To do that in Xamarin.Forms you should add new create new `Style` in `ResourceDictionary` for specific `TargetType`.

Example `Style` for Label class:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
     <Style x:Key="labelRedStyle" TargetType="Label">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions"Value="Center" />
         <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center" />
         <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
         <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15,10" />
     </Style>
<ResourceDicrionary>
```

And example usage:

```
<Grid>
    <Label Style="myLabelStyle" />
</Grid>
```

Let me know if it helped! Waiting for more questions :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is Xamarin.Forms and not WPF but if your `DataTemplate` is used by a ListView it is missing a `ViewCell`.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderContainerStyle">
    <ViewCell>
        <Label Margin="10" Text="{Binding}"/>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
```

However, if your `DataTemplate` is used in your own custom control that was created then the `ViewCell` may not be needed and another issue with that control may be the cause of why `Margin` is not working.

Comment: Should have mentioned, this is originally what I tried but it threw an exception System.ArgumentException: Value was an invalid value for HeaderTemplate
Parameter name: value

Comment: Are you trying to use the DataTemplate as a resource for a DataTemplateSelector or are you just trying to use it as a style for your label? Perhaps adding more code showing how you're trying to use it on your page would help.